# Python directory conflicts with python executable location

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, directory

I have a python executable I wish to run from PowerShell using the command `python [executable].py`.

First I changed the directory in PowerShell to the location of the executable using `cd path\to\my\directory` which worked fine. However whenever I tried to use python to execute my code, PowerShell immediately searches for the `[executable].py` in Python's installation folder - fails to find it - and gives the an error that it cannot find the appropriate file.

How do I make sure that Powershell looks for the executable in the directory I indicated as opposed to the default Python installation folder?

[image: Screenshot Attached]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run `python.exe` from a location other than the installation directory you'd call it with its full path:

```
& 'C:\path\to\python.exe' 'your.py'
```

If you want to run it from the current directory, prepend the filename with the relative path `.\`:

```
& .\python.exe 'your.py'
```

If you call an executable without a path like this:

```
& python.exe 'your.py'
```

PowerShell will look for a matching file in the directories listed in the `$env:PATH` environment variable, and execute the first match (or report an error if no matching file can be found).

With that said, the error you got in your screenshot is not because of the Python interpreter, but because of the file you want the interpreter to run. You're calling

```
python conditions
```

when you actually want to run

```
python conditions.py
```

Neither PowerShell nor Python magically add the extension for you. Instead they report an error because a file `conditions` (without an extension) simply doesn't exist.